# Como descobrir o delimitador CSV pelo PHP?

Tags: php, csv

Um arquivo CSV pode variar os delimitadores. Já vi sendo usado `;` (ponto-e-virgula), `,` (vírgula) e até `\t` (tab).

No PHP, sei que é possível capturar os valores do CSV informando o delimitador:

```php
$delimitador = ';';

$arquivo = fopen('meu_csv.csv', 'r');

$cabecalho = fgetcsv($arquivo, 0, $delimitador);

if (feof($arquivo)) {
    exit('Você importou um CSV vazio');
}


while ($linha = fgetcsv($arquivo, 0, $delimitador)) {
    $linhas[] = array_combine($cabecalho, array_map('trim', $linha));
}
```

Porém, ao invés de usar um delimitador fixo, preciso descobrir qual é o delimitador usado em um arquivo CSV. Existe alguma forma  de fazer isso em PHP? Qual seria a maneira mais apropriada?

Comment: O PhoSpreadsheet infere o delimitador com uma abordagem estatística: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/02f37d4f7e353480c07e33ad912da2b859bcceec/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Csv/Delimiter.php#L67

Answer (score 6):

Usar `strpos` ou `preg_match` pode conflitar, pois alguns CSV podem vir assim:

```
"foo,bar","Nome";"Telefone"
```

Ou então:

```
"foo,bar";"Nome","Telefone"
```

Dependendo do tipo de checagem como:

```
$handle = fopen('arquivo.csv', 'r');

preg_match('/[;,\t]/', fgets($handle), $matches);

$delimitador = $matches[0] ?? null;

var_dump($delimitador);
```

No exemplo acima testando com `"foo,bar";"Nome","Telefone"` irá gerar essa saída:

```
string(1) ","
```

Quando o correto seria *ponto e vírgula* `;`, detectar o escape (não falo do escape propriamente, que é algo que pode ser ajustado, mas geralmente é usado o `\`) é um tanto quanto complicado de fazer manualmente, o ideal seria usar o próprio `fgetcsv()`, mas claro que de qualquer forma tem que informar o delimitador antes.

Todos editores que usei antes de abrir o arquivo solicitam que o usuário informe o delimitador antes, dando geralmente algumas sugestões antes ou até uma sugestão customizada, exemplo no **Calc (LibreOffice)**:

> [image: Calc (LibreOffice)]

Então a ideia é que o usuário informe o delimitador e então o seu script valida o validador usando o próprio `fgetcsv()`, então no front-end pode fazer algo como:

```
<select name="delimitador">
    <option value=";">;</option>
    <option value=",">,</option>
    <option value="\t">\t (TAB)</option>
</select>
```

Você pode adicionar valores customizados, já que o delimitador pode variar, isso é apenas um exemplo.

No back-end você pode validar assim:

```
$delimitador = $_POST['delimitador'];

if (!in_array($delimitador, [ '.', ',', "\t" ])) {
    die('Delimitador inválido!');
}

$arquivo = fopen('meu_csv.csv', 'r') or die('Não pode ler o arquivo');

// Obtém o cabeçalho conforme instrução do usuário
$cabecalho = fgetcsv($arquivo, 0, $delimitador);

// Se o delimitador não tiver um numero aceitável de linhas irá falhar
if (count($cabecalho) < 2) {
    die('Delimitador inválido para esse arquivo!');
}

print_r($cabecalho);
```

Dessa forma irá contar se retornou pelo menos 2 colunas, um valor que você pode ajustar também, mas aqui cabe apenas para exemplo. O `fgetcsv()` reconhece o que esta escapado.

Lembrando que você pode ajustar outros parâmetros:

```
fgetcsv( resource $stream , int $length = 0 , string $separator = "," , string $enclosure = '"' , string $escape = "\\" ) : array
```

O que você pode passar para o usuário configurar antes de enviar o arquivo, mas ainda sim usar o mesmo processo de "validação", contanto o numero mínimo de colunas.

Não vou dizer que não tem meio de detectar, mas o tanto de trabalho que vai gerar criando um script assim será tornar o processo mais lento e possivelmente falho, fora a complicação de `separator`, `enclosure` ou `escape` customizados no documento CSV do usuário. E sim, existem libs prontas que prometem detectar isso, mas me parece um canhão pra matar formigas e se de fato isso fosse de detectar automaticamente fosse realmente bom não seria necessário programas como **Calc** (libreoffice) permitir o usuário configurar na pré-visualização (se eu não me engano o MSExcel também tem algo assim).

## Detectando possíveis delimitadores CSV automaticamente

Mas mesmo que você queira insistir nisso recomendo limitar os delimitadores permitidos e usar ainda o `fgetcsv` combinado [**`rewind`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php) para cada teste, algo como:

```
$delimitadoresPermitidos = array( ',', ';', "\t" );

$arquivo = fopen('meu_csv.csv', 'r') or die('Não pode ler o arquivo');

$detectado = null;
$cabecalho = null;

foreach ($delimitadores as $delimitador) {

   // Para cada delimitador testado é necessário voltar a primeira linha
   rewind($arquivo);

   $cabecalho = fgetcsv($arquivo, 0, $delimitador);

   // Se retornar false é porque existe algum erro ou o documento possivelmente esta vazio
   if ($cabecalho === false) {
       die('Arquivo provavelmente vazio');
   }

   // Se o delimitador testado retornar 2 ou mais colunas então irá usar esse delimitador
   if (count($cabecalho) > 1) {
       $detectado = $delimitador;
       break;
   }
}

if ($detectado === null) {
    die('Documento inválido');
}

// Cabeçalho
print_r($cabecalho);

// Lê outras linhas usando o delimitador detectado
while (($linha = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $detectado)) !== FALSE) {
    print_r($linha);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Eu utilizei uma validação dupla, fiz um fgetcsv usando o delimitador virgula  e um fgetcsv  usando o ponto e virgula o que retornasse mais posições era o delimitador do arquivo.

```
$delimitador = ',';

$validaPontoEVirgula = fgetcsv($arquivo,0,';','"');
$validaVirgula = fgetcsv($arquivo,0,',','"');


if(count($validaPontoEVirgula) > count($validaVirgula) ){
    $delimitador = ';';
}else{
    $delimitador = ',';
}
```